# XCode constantly hangs

Tags: xcode, macos

I run XCode on VMWare with latest macOS and latest XCode. It always hangs, especially when debugging, if it crashes or hits a breakpoint it will freeze and if you type a bunch in Xcode while it is frozen it will sometimes pick back up and go to the breakpoint. Once it freezes/unfreezes like this, all of the following breakpoints will hit smoothly, until you rerun and then it goes through the same. Stopping a project has the same issue. I always thought it was because it was a VM even though my laptop specs were good, but randomly a few days ago it ran perfectly for days, until I restarted the VM today and now it is back to doing it again. The only thing I can think I did a few days ago that maybe solved it temporarily was that I was messing around with installing node on the mac. Can anybody point me in the right direction to how to fix it, since I now know my computer specs are not the issue?

To add: The autocomplete in XCode all still works when frozen, I can move around and work, etc. What it is, is that it pauses at the breakpoint, but does not go to the breakpoint for like 10 mins in Xcode to where you can actually hit play again, so the simulator is frozen and it makes it impossible to debug.

Comment: is your VMWare running on top of a mac machine? If not, then that's the probable reason.

Answer (score 0):

**There could be couple of reasons behind it, Please try following :**

1. clean up the temporary cache files in the developer dir in library both for the current user and on HDD.

   - Remove ~/Library/Developer/
   - Remove ~/Library/Caches
   - Remove ~/Library/Autosave Information
2. Try making a new User acc and test the same project. A new user will have no caches for any apps.
3. Please check the both the memory slots read installed RAM.
4. If all the above not helps please re-install a fresh Xcode. I think your Xcode version is updated from previous version and not freshly installed.

Comment: Did these and they made it worse, if anything, thanks though

Comment: May I know what steps you followed ? Also if you made a new user, login to the user and left your MAC free for 30 minutes so that indexing can take place freely. Immediately using a freshly made user Account will show slow performance.

Comment: Still if it is showing slow performance overall, I am afraid there are bad sectors in the Harddisk. Faced a similar issue on Mac Book Pro and reason was connecting cable between HDD and motherboard/logicboard.

Comment: I just did 1 and it didn't work, so just did 4 and let it index yes

Comment: Not sure where to look for three, but it has 8GB if RAM and shows this under memory: 1 memory slot in use, 127 available